# Firebase Realtime Database - storing multiple nodes from user inputs

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to Firebase and android studio and I'm trying to get multiple nodes to save in Firebase, I've got a node to save for 'Users' but I need another one for a 'Budgets' category to save. Originally I thought there was an issue with my OnClickListener but on inspection it's working fine. 
This is the code for sending user data in my registration :

```
 private void sendUserData(){
        String UserID = firebaseAuth.getUid();
        RegDB regDB = new RegDB(emailDb, nameDb, passwordDb);
        mDatabase.child("Users").child(UserID).setValue(regDB);
    }
```

And this is the code for in my Budgets page to send user data:

```
 private void sendUserData() {
        String UserID = firebaseAuth.getUid();
        CategoriesDB catDb = new CategoriesDB(travel_budget, entertainment_budget, fitness_budget, beauty_budget, clothes_budget, holiday_budget, food_budget, mobile_budget);
        mDatabase.child("Users").child(UserID).child("Categories").setValue(catDb);
    }
```

I keep getting this error once I try to enter in budgets, although Firebase is assigning a unique userID for each person who registers and this ID is being stored in the Real Time Database and Authentication :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()
```

For reference this is my OnClickListener for my Registration page:

```
button_Upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (validate()) {
                    String emailDb = email.getText().toString().trim();
                    String passwordDb = password.getText().toString().trim();

                    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailDb, passwordDb).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                sendUserData();
                                firebaseAuth.signOut();
                                Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Successfully Registered!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                finish();
                                startActivity(new Intent(Register.this, Menu.class));
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Registration Failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Also the OnClickListener for my Budgets page:

```
btn_subCat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(validate()){
                sendUserData();
                Toast.makeText(Categories.this, "Completed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(Categories.this, Menu.class ));
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(Categories.this, "Submission failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: Log the UserID. getUid() might not be returning anything

Comment: The userID assigned from firebase is coming up in my logcat like this: '/traktrail.example.com D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( 1JSfWVLNBQUDMDlbIT3mlqYJC6W2 ).
/traktrail.example.com D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying auth state listeners about user ( 1JSfWVLNBQUDMDlbIT3mlqYJC6W2 ). '

Answer (score 0):

I am not really experienced, but I believe that I have into a similar problem while trying to fetch and update information from an API. I think that your problem comes from multi-threading. When you call the getUid() function it creates a new thread to fetch the needed information. This tread needs some time to complete its task and fetch the id from the database. However, your sendUserData() function takes less time to complete its task. Thus you get to the third line of the code from the sendUserData() function where you use your UserID variable before the thread has finished, leaving you with a null variable.

If this is the problem, you can solve it by getting the application to wait for the thread to complete or you can fetch the user id before tapping on the button. I think that the first approach is better, however when I tackled my problem I was not able to find a good way of doing this.

For the second approach you can simply create you UserID variable in the begging of the onCreate() method and assign it's value there. By doing this you will create the thread when the activity is created, take the information from the database and close the thready. When you will try to call your sendUserData() function you will already have the userId ready for you.

So, not sure if this is it, but give it a try :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Unfortunately I still can't get it to work :( but I really appreciate you taking your time to help me :)